# Degree of the minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ in $U(\theta-1,\theta+1)$ distribution

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample from the Uniform distribution over the interval $(\theta-1,\theta+1)$. By the factorization theorem, it is clear that the order statistics $Y_1=X_\left(1\right)$ and $Y_n=X_\left(n\right)$ are joint sufficient statistics for $\theta$. Now, because $$\theta-1 < Y_1 < Y_n < \theta+1 $$ implies that $Y_n -1 < \theta < Y_1 + 1$, choosing $\hat\theta \in (Y_n-1,Y_1+1)$ will force the likelihood function to achieve its maximum; that is, $$L(\hat\theta)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n, \forall \hat\theta\in(Y_n-1,Y_1+1)$$

Typically, statisticians takes the value for $\hat\theta$ to be the midrange of $Y_1,Y_n$: $\hat\theta=\frac{Y_1+Y_n}{2}$.

Now, because such a value for $\hat\theta$ maximizes the likelihood function, it follows that $\hat\theta$ is an *mle* for $\theta$ of in $Unif(\theta-1,\theta+1)$. It is noted in the Hogg, McKean, Craig textbook "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" ($7^{th}$ edition), however, that even though $\hat\theta$ is an *mle* of $\theta$ and a function of the joint sufficient statistics $Y_1,Y_n$ for $\theta$, it does not represent a minimal sufficient statistic; this is because $\hat\theta$ is itself *not* a sufficient statistic for theta.

What I'm wondering here is $why$ $\hat\theta = \frac{Y_1+Y_n}{2}$ is not a sufficient statistic for $\theta$. By the definition of a sufficient statistic and using the factorization theorem, $Y_1,Y_n$ being the joint sufficient statistics for $\theta$ imply that the likelihood function can be written as $$\prod_1^nf(x_i;\theta) = K_1(Y_1,Y_n;\theta)*K_2(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$$ where $K_1(Y_1,Y_2;\theta)$ depends on $x_1,...x_n$ only through $Y_1,Y_n$ and$K_2(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ does not depend upon $\theta$; in our case, $$K_1(Y_1,Y_n;\theta)=\left(\frac1{2}\right)^n \cdot \mathbf 1_{(\theta-1,\theta+1)}(Y_1) \cdot \mathbf 1_{(\theta-1,\theta+1)}(Y_n) $$

Now, although it is clear that we cannot reduce the product of the two indicator functions down any further to any *single* order statistic $Y_i$ such that an equality remains between $K_1$ and our new function, why is it not the case that $$\mathbf 1_{(\theta-1,\theta+1)}(\frac{Y_1+Y_2}{2}) \neq \mathbf 1_{(\theta-1,\theta+1)}(Y_1) \cdot \mathbf 1_{(\theta-1,\theta+1)}(Y_n)$$ is a valid equality?

In proceeding further in my reasoning, let's reference [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354893/sufficient-statistics-for-uniform-%CE%B8-%CE%B8). For an overview, this question revolves around the sufficient statistics for the uniform distribution $Unif(-\theta,\theta)$. In this problem, one can reduce their argument from the joint sufficient statistics $X_\left(1\right),X_\left(n\right)$ down to the single sufficient statistic $max\{X_\left(1\right),X_\left(n\right)\}=Y^*$.

**Does it happen to be so that the only thing stopping us from reducing our two-dimensional joint sufficient statistic(s), $\mathbf Y=(Y_1,Y_n)$, for $\theta$ down into the single-dimensional ("minimal") sufficient statistic, $Y=Y^*$, for $\theta$ the fact that our Uniform distribution is not distributed symmetrically about the Y-axis?** I could see this argument being the case, but I'd like to be sufficiently (no pun intended) sure of that before proceeding on in my studies. It took me quite a bit of investigating to begin to understand how to work through various operations when working with the indicator function, so I still might a little lost when it comes to the finer intricacies of manipulating this function.

Answer (score 2):

Now I hate to be the one to answer my own question, but I feel that in the time it took me to formulate my question in MathJax, I might have arrived at the answer.

First, let's look at *why* the reduction of degree from two-dimensions to one-dimension for a (joint) sufficient statistic vector for $\theta$ of the Uniform distribution works for symmetrical arguments:

Suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample from the symmetric Uniform distribution $Unif(-\theta,\theta)$. By the factorization theorem, it is easy to verify that the vector $\mathbf Y = (Y_1,Y_2)$ where $Y_1 = X_\left(1\right)$ and $Y_2=X_\left(n\right)$ is a joint sufficient vector of degree two for $\theta$, with $$K_1(Y_1,Y_2;\theta)=(\frac{1}{2})^n \cdot \mathbf 1_{(-\theta,\theta)}(Y_1) \cdot \mathbf 1_{(-\theta,\theta)}(Y_n)$$

From the two indicator functions and from the definition of order statistics, we have that $$-\theta<Y_1<Y_n<\theta \implies \theta>-Y_1 \land \theta>Y_n$$

This allows us to use the maximum function concurrently on $-Y_1$ and $Y_n$ to put a restriction on $\theta$, meaning that this result, $Y^* = max\{-Y_1,Y_n\}$, is such that $$\mathbf 1_{(-\theta,\theta)}(Y_1) \cdot \mathbf 1_{(-\theta,\theta)}(Y_n) = \mathbf 1_{(-\theta,\theta)}(Y^*)$$ is a valid equality.

On the other hand, suppose $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ is a random sample from the Uniform distribution $Unif(\theta-1,\theta+1)$. By the factorization theorem, it is easy to verify that the vector $\mathbf Y = (Y_1,Y_2)$ where $Y_1 = X_\left(1\right)$ and $Y_2=X_\left(n\right)$ is a joint sufficient vector of degree two for $\theta$, with $$K_1(Y_1,Y_2;\theta)=(\frac{1}{2})^n \cdot \mathbf 1_{(\theta-1,\theta+1)}(Y_1) \cdot \mathbf 1_{(\theta-1,\theta+1)}(Y_n)$$

From the two indicator functions and from the definition of order statistics, we have that $$\theta-1<Y_1<Y_n<\theta+1 \implies Y_1+1>\theta \land Y_n-1<\theta$$

Because now we have $\theta$ sandwiched between two restrictions ("variables", for our purposes) and without the benefit of appealing to the symmetry of the situation, **we have no tools available to ourselves to condense the information provided from $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ any further.** Thus, we must concede that the joint sufficient statistics $Y_1$ and $Y_n$ are joint minimal sufficient statistics for $\theta$ for a non-symmetric Uniform distribution. On the other hand, we have also shown that $Y^*=max\{Y_1,Y_n\}$ is the single-dimensional and (thus) minimal sufficient sufficient statistic for $\theta$ for a symmetric Uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2):

$(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Proof:

The joint density of $X=(X_1, \cdots,X_n)$ is $$\mathbb{1}(\theta-\frac{1}{2}\leq X_{i}\leq \theta+\frac{1}{2}),\forall i$$
This is equivalent to say
$$\mathbb{1}(\theta\leq X_{(1)}+\frac{1}{2}\text{ and } \theta\geq X_{(n)}-\frac{1}{2})$$
Thus $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ uniquely determines the area where the p.d.f is one, which means $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ uniquely determines the shape of the log-likelihood function.
We can conclude $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.